# Терминал на php

Tags: php

Как реализовать что-то похожее на терминал, т.е входишь, авторизируешься, далее просто посылаешь команды , например, `echo myname` - выводится имя в профиле или просто обычный текст из бд; только бд в текстовом файле будет, например, `echo 1` - выводится текст из бд.

Comment: Что-то не то вы мне предлагаете! Мне надо чисто для себя) например, ввёл я в поле echo 1 - из базы берётся значение echo 1.

Comment: <i>из базы берётся значение echo 1</i><br/>
Это как?

Comment: Проще говоря, просто что я ввожу в поле, то и выводится, например: help; то, что и есть в базе под значением help, и выводится; надеюсь поняли!

Comment: Может вам просто [phpmyadmin][1] установить?

  [1]: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

Comment: Я говорю на php.

Comment: А он, по вашему, на чем написан? На ассемблере?

Answer (score 3):

Ничего писать не нужно. [Всё уже сделано](http://www.google.com/?q=php%20shell). Например, [PHP Shell](http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/). Если надо выполнять какие-то специальные команды, то тогда можно парсить да выполнять. Может, с помощью [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).